# How can I use one instance of page.php to display different custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

At the moment I'm using multiple page templates to display custom posts (page-events.php, page-resources.php) and it seems wasteful.

How can I reuse page.php and just display the post type relating to the page a user has clicked on?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're using page templates incorrectly. Is page-events.php for a single event, or a list of events? See the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for how WordPress decides which template to use. If you have pages that are lists of posts in a custom post type, then that should be an archive and use the appropriate template.

Comment: It's a list of events (or resources or programmes), which you can click to go to a single event (which I've yet to implement). So if I use an archive, should I create just one for all post types or one archive for each? And if it's possible to display posts based on type, from one template, any ideas where to look/what to search for?

Comment: This is all stuff WordPress does automatically. You don't create pages for archives, you just register the post type and the archive URL is created automatically. The template hierarchy, which I linked, decides which template file gets used, but all the templates should use the [standard loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/). I suggest reading through the [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll get reading